# Word for "mixed letters"

Tags: word-request

I have seen:

> Fill out the form in **block letters.**

and

> Write your name in **small letters.**

But I wonder what I should say

> when I am using **both.**

Is it,

**running letter?**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The technically correct term to use about the size of letters is **[case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_case)**. **Capital** or **block** letters are called **upper-case**. **Small** letters (many of which, btw, are the same height as upper-case) are **lower-case**. Writing that is made up of a mixture of the two is called **mixed-case**.

The term **running letters** actually refers to **[cursive writing](https://www.1001fonts.com/cursive-fonts.html)**, where the majority of letters are joined to their neighbours. There is some possibility for confusion because, generally, lower case writing can be cursive, but upper case writing is generally not cursive.